# Listen to voice command in Android

Tags: android, command, voice

Is it possible that an android app can listen to voice commands all the time without any other user input?

Answer (score 1):

Speech Input is the API you're looking for, and you would use the API linked below;

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html

Here, you will find the RecognitionListener interface which you need;

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html

Comment: The first link does not work.  The second does not provide any useful description about how to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible Android has a Speech to Text APi in it. Get the user input as speech and convert it into String. Based on your string output you can do operations on your application.

Check this post for getting more info on speech to text API

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Comment: Actually, that appears to be TTS, not Speach-To-Text